# Branch.io failing to attribute Google Ads with SKAdNetwork - Why?

Tags: ios, swift, analytics, branch.io, attribution

We've correctly configured our Branch x Google AdWords integration (it shows "working" in the Branch partner management and "linked" in Google Ad's linked 3rd party attributors). We've correctly configured our SKAdNetwork integration (it shows install events for a_google_adwords in the SKAdNetwork section of Branch).

However, Branch doesn't show any activity for the Google Ads campaign in the Ads > Analytics section, and zero info is making its way from Branch to Google Ads.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Does anyone have a means of contacting Branch support? Can anyone recommend attribution providers that are more reliable than Branch with SKAdNetwork attribution?

Thanks, all.

Comment: Hey, I don't know the answer for this but I'm in a similar boat. I'm integrating Branch and Google Ads but do I need to do something special to enable Google Ads's SKAdNetwork because we're not seeing anything in the Branch Dashboard or GA SKAdNetwork's reporting > SKAdNetwork. Would really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

I work for an app marketing agency named Wuzzon that has clients with Branch, running into the same problem.

Since iOS google ads campaigns only send postbacks through SKAN data, you need to check under Ads --> SKAdNetwork in order to be able to see that data that Google Ads sends back.

Google uses a click reporting methodology that updates data retroactively on a daily basis, which means that most MMP's have to ask for data from a timeperiod in the past (often a few days ago to 2 weeks ago, depending on the timeframe of your SKAN conversion mapping) and display the install under the last click before the install date.

You can check the following links for more info about the Google Ads integration with SKAN for branch: https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/google-skadnetwork and https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/ad-networks-supporting-skadnetwork.